# Multiple Regression Models vs. Single Regression Model

Tags: regression, sampling, mean, bootstrap, model

I had the following question about **Multiple Regression Models vs.  Single Regression Model**

Suppose you have a standard regression problem: there is a dataset with several covariates and a single response variable - you want to fit a linear regression model to this data with the objective of predicting the response variable for new observations in the future.

**Case 1:** You can fit a standard linear regression model to this data

**Case 2:** You can perform the following:

- Step 1: Take a 10% random sample (with replacement) from the data
- Step 2: Fit a standard linear regression model to this sampled data from Step 1
- Step 3: Repeat Step 1 and Step 2 "n" times - you now have "n" linear regression models
- Step 4: For predicting an unseen observation, have each of the "n" models individually make a prediction - then, take the average of these "n" predictions. This averaged prediction can be considered as the final prediction

**My Question:** Is the approach suggested in Case 2 a valid approach?

Is Case 2 already being used in statistical modelling under a different name (e.g. "Bootstrap Regression")? I thought that perhaps such an approach might "overfit" the data less - but I am not sure if Case 2 will just end up being equal to Case 1. Could Case 2 provide more realistic error estimates on the regression parameters and the predictions?

Thanks!

Comment: A fly in the ointment for your proposal is that the OLS predictions have smaller variance by the Gauss-Markov Theorem.

Comment: @ BigBendRegion : Thank you for your reply! This is the kind of insight I am looking for!